# How to describe the weather with variety in French?

Tags: choix-de-mot

Since I've been learning French I've seen the phrase "Il fait beau" about a million times. So I can certainly say "It's nice out." But in English I could also say:

- The weather is amazing!
- The weather is gorgeous! It's gorgeous out! It's gorgeous outside!
- You should see what it's like outside!
- What a gorgeous day!
- Beautiful weather today.
- Lovely day, isn't it?

And so on! There's a billion ways I could express this. And in French right now I'm stuck with "Il fait beau" because I don't know what else is allowed! For instance, can I say "Le temps est...[adjective]"?

Comment: *If fait beau* qualifie le temps, les exemples cités renvoient à des émotions liées aux beau temps ; elles peuvent être traduites de la même manière en français sans trop de difficultés.

Comment: @cl-r Pas vraiment de traductions telles quelles, chaque langue a son stock de locutions idiomatiques qui servent dans la fonction phatique du langage et  qui ne sont pas toujours transposables.

Comment: Je pourrais faire du copier coller de ce qu'on trouve sur internet...  c'est un peu "basique dans les cours de FLE (français langue étrangère). http://lewebpedagogique.com/ressources-fle/files/2011/02/soleil-anim%C3%A9.gif  - http://www.ph-ludwigsburg.de/html/2b-frnz-s-01/overmann/baf4/4c.htm  -   http://www.bonjourdefrance.com/n11/meteo.html - etc. etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can say “Le temps est …”

A rough translation of “the weather” in French is “*le temps*” or “*la météo*”. So for all of your listed example, there is an equivalant in French.

- Le temps est génial./La météo est géniale.
- Le temps est magnifique.
- Il fait bon dehors.
- Tu devrais voir le temps dehors!
- Quelle belle journée. (You shouldn't really use it because people might think you are referring to the day you're having, not the weather. But in theory, this works).

And so on…

Comment: I would distinguish *“temps”* (which can mean weather) and *“météo”* (which usually means weather *prediction*).

Comment: It does mean those things , but people use them this way nonetheless.

Answer (score 6):

You can virtually use any adjective with "Il fait ...".

"Il fait : jour, nuit, froid, chaud, doux, ventueux, humide, glacial, brumeux, lourd, moite, beau, bon, mauvais, moche, sombre, clair, triste, magnifique, étouffant ... "

Children say "Il fait soleil dehors"(but NEVER say "Il fait pluie, vent, orage")

Adjectives expressing a human-like feeling are preferably to be used with "Le temps est" : "Le temps était triste, mélancolique, joyeux, serein, radieux, favorable, insupportable, aimable, grincheux, pesant ... "

One can use adverbs : "Il fait insupportablement chaud", "Il fait délicieusement frais", "Il fait super beau/ hyper froid"  "Il fait effroyablement glacial"

IL Y A du vent, du soleil, un beau soleil, des (gros) nuages, de la grêle, de la neige, du gel.

VERBS like pleuvoir, geler, grêler : IL PLEUT, il grêle, il gèle, ON gèle ici (people freezing in a house). On se les gèle (very cold, fam.). J'étouffe!

ÇA caille, Ça pèle. (Cold, fam.)

QUEL temps spendide! Quelle belle journée! Quel beau soleil ! Quel temps de chien / de canard / de m*****! Quelle averse !
C'EST UN TEMPS RÊVÉ pour aller pêcher, chasser, faire du ski, faire une promenade, un pique-nique... 
"Il fait un temps à ne pas mettre un chat dehors" (very rainy)
"Ooooh, regarde! Un arc-en-ciel!"

And many other